# Lazy match does not work as expected

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
abc1def1ghij2klmc
```

and I am trying to build a regex that extracts the shortest (lazy) string between 1 and 2. In the above example, I need to extract `1ghij2`

The regex `1.*2` matches `1def1ghij2`

The lazy regex `1.*?2` matches `1def1ghij2`

How do I extract the shortest string between 1 and 2?

I expected lazy match work here. Perhaps I misunderstood the lazy match concept?

Comment: Try `1[^12]*2`. That says find the substring starting with `1`, containing no `1` or `2`, and ending in `2`. Will this work?

Comment: Try `1[^12]*2`.  Hope that helps.

Comment: The way I think about it is this: the lazy qualifier tells the regex when it can stop. With `1.*?2`, once the engine finds a 1, it’s going to keep going till it finds a `2`—so it’d match `11111112`. One way to get what you want is to disallow `1`s and `2`s in between the starting `1` and final `2`, as suggested.

Comment: Negated character classes are also faster as the regex engine doesn't need to backtrack.

Comment: As an option: `[^1]*?(?=2)`, although it doesn't capture `1` and `2` (i.e. only inner text)

Answer (score 2):

```
1[^12]*2
```

**you can see how the matching of your original pattern works in detail, all the regex engine steps one by one, here: https://regex101.com/r/x22lDS/1/debugger**

**an explanation of this regex run in human language:**
the regex engine checks your target text, on whether your pattern matches something or not, starting at the beginning of your text (letter "a"), then it continues one character after another to the right with no match, up to the first "1", matches it and then continues in matching one character after another and matches them all till "2" including. Therefore also the second "1" is matched. See the included link above to see it in action.

*You can try to put another "2" to the right of your existing "2", run your original pattern in the regex101.com and you can see that it matches the same string as before, not expanding it - the lazy functionality works, in this case, this way.*

hope this helps :)